# Sum of Binomial Coefficients not Zero

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ arbitrary with $a > b$.
Is that true that

$$\sum_{j=0}^b (-1)^j\binom{a}{j}\binom{b}{j} \neq 0$$

Till now I wasn't able to find a conterexample but also my attempts to prove it fail.

I get only $\sum_{j=0}^b (-1)^j\binom{a}{j}\binom{b}{j} = \sum_{j=0}^b (-1)^j \frac{a!b!}{(a-j)!(b-j)(j!)^2}$. Does anybody see the key how to cope with it?

Comment: Do not know if this helps, but the sum you write will be the $x^a$-coefficient of $(1-x)^a(1+x)^b = (1-x^2)^b(1-x)^{a-b}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is less of an answer, but more of a guide.  Because

$$\binom{b}{j}=\binom{b}{b-j}$$

you can rewrite your sum as

$$S_{a,b}=\sum_{j=0}^b(-1)^j\binom{a}{j}\binom{b}{b-j}$$

which is an alternating version of [Chu-Vandermonde's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) identity

Also, [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94501/alternating-sign-vandermonde-convolution) might help you get further in your calculation.  It looks like their might be similarities between your alternating sum...