# Find the value of $A,$ a summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> If $n$ is even then find the value of $$S=\binom{n}{0}\binom{n+5}{n}+\binom{n}{2}\binom{n+5}{n-2}+\binom{n}{4}\binom{n+5}{n-4}+\cdots$$

If somehow I can find the value of $$A=\binom{n}{1}\binom{n+5}{n-1}+\binom{n}{3}\binom{n+5}{n-3}+\binom{n}{5}\binom{n+5}{n-5}+\cdots$$ I can found the value of original expression. Because, $$S=\binom{2n+5}{n}-A$$
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I considered coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n\cdot(1+x)^{n+5}$ but here we also counted some unwanted terms whose sum is $A$.

Comment: @AnneBauval did

Comment: This is the (particular case of) [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) you already wrote before, but what are *your* attempts about *your* question?

Comment: This identity, together with [that less known one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94505/386889), answers your question.

Comment: ? "Your" $A+S=\dots$ includes "odd" terms and *is* (a particular case of)  Vandermonde. I was asking for some more efforts.

Comment: Consider the expression: $$\frac14[(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n][(1+x)^{n+5}+(1-x)^{n+5}].$$